# Bash Script unwanted compute the key of an associative array

Tags: bash

```
ASS_ARR["20221005-130001"]="CIAO"
ASS_ARR["20221004-130001"]="TEST"

echo "${!ASS_ARR[@]}"

for KEY in "${!ASS_ARR[@]}"; do
  echo $KEY
done
```

**Output of the Keys**

```
# sh ./test.sh
20091003 20091004
20091003
20091004
```

Basicaly will subtract 130001 to 20221005
How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Don't use `sh` to execute a script that needs to be executed with `bash`. Even if `sh` is a link to `bash`, certain features may be disabled when executed as `sh`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But with bash It still be evaluated in an arithmetic context as explain by tjm3772's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the array as associative, otherwise it's a default indexed array where the index is evaluated in an arithmetic context.

```
declare -A ASS_ARR
ASS_ARR["20221005-130001"]="CIAO"
ASS_ARR["20221004-130001"]="TEST"

echo "${!ASS_ARR[@]}"

for KEY in "${!ASS_ARR[@]}"; do
  echo $KEY
done
```